# Does a module with the following properties necessarily finite length?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a f.g. $R$-module, and suppose there exists a non-zero $r\in R$ such that $rM=0$. Does $M$ have finite length?

Comment: Did you want to have $r\neq 0$?

Comment: This is definitively true over the rings (PIDs) where we have a good handle on f.g. modules, of course.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=k[x,y]/(y^2)$ where $k$ is a field. Let $M=(y)=\{yf\mid f\in k[x]\}$, which is a finitely generated $R$-module; indeed, it is generated by the element $y$. We also have that $yM=0$. However, there is an infinite chain of submodules
$$(y)\supseteq (xy)\supseteq (x^2y)\supseteq\cdots$$
so $M$ is of infinite length.

Comment: Your module is better identified as the ideal $(y)$, I think; at least the notation is clearer.

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pick a ring $S$ which has a f.g. module $M$ which is not of finite length. Let $R=S[X]$, and turn $M$ into an $R$-module by declaring that elements of $S$ act as they should and $X\cdot m=0$ for all $m\in M$.

Comment: For example, pick them as in Zev's answer :-)